# How to make Zero to Many Relationship in Prisma (0 - N)

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, prisma

Following the Prisma.io.docs documentation, theres nothing saying about zero to many relationships.

I'm developing a daily nutrition system.
I have the following modeling where I want an InfoNutriDay to have at least 01 food or at least 01 meal. Example:

1. InfoNutriDay can be saved with several foods and no meal.
2. InfoNutriDay can be saved with several meals and no food
3. InfoNutriDay can be saved with several foods and several meals

**How can I make prisma.create correctly where it would allow me to record according to the above?**

See my current model:

```
model infonutriday {
  id                     String                   @id @db.VarChar(145)
  date                   DateTime                 @db.Date
  portion                Float                    @db.Float
  protein                Float                    @db.Float
  calories               Float                    @db.Float
  grease                 Float                    @db.Float
  salt                   Float                    @db.Float
  finalizedDay           Int                      @db.TinyInt

  infonutriday_has_meals infonutriday_has_meals[]
  infonutriday_has_foods infonutriday_has_foods[]
  infonutriday_has_users infonutriday_has_users[]
}

model infonutriday_has_meals {
  infonutriday_id String       @db.VarChar(45)
  infonutriday    infonutriday @relation(fields: [infonutriday_id], references: [id])

  meals_id Int
  meals    Meal @relation(fields: [meals_id], references: [id])

  @@id([infonutriday_id, meals_id])
}

model infonutriday_has_foods {
  infonutriday_id String
  infonutriday    infonutriday @relation(fields: [infonutriday_id], references: [id])

  foods_id Int
  foods    Food @relation(fields: [foods_id], references: [id])

  @@id([infonutriday_id, foods_id])
}

model infonutriday_has_users {
  infonutriday_id String       @db.VarChar(45)
  infonutriday    infonutriday @relation(fields: [infonutriday_id], references: [id])

  users_id Int
  users    User @relation(fields: [users_id], references: [id])

  @@id([infonutriday_id, users_id])
}
```

And when doing a prisma.create with the following:

```
infonutriday_has_foods: foods_id ? {
                    create: {
                        foods: {
                            connect: foods_id.map((foodId: number) => (
                                {
                                    id: foodId,
                                }
                            ))
                        },
                    },
                } : undefined,

                infonutriday_has_meals: meals_id ? {
                    create: {
                        meals: {
                            connect: meals_id.map((mealId: number) => (
                                {
                                    id: mealId,
                                }
                            ))

                        },
                    },
                } : undefined,
```

it returns me an error:

```
const newInfoNutriDay = await prisma.infonutriday.create({
        data: {
          id: "04-ago-2023+1696526834318",
          date: "2023-08-03T22:00:00.000Z",
          portion: 33,
          protein: 33,
          calories: 33,
          grease: 33,
          salt: 3,
          finalizedDay: 0,
          infonutriday_has_foods: {
            create: {
              foods: {
                connect: [
                  {
                    id: 1
                  }
                ]
                ~~~~~~~~~
              }
            }
          },
          infonutriday_has_meals: {
            create: {
              meals: {
                connect: [
                  {
                    id: 4
                  },
                  {
                    id: 3
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          infonutriday_has_users: {
            create: {
              users: {
                connect: {
                  id: 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        include: {
          infonutriday_has_foods: {
            include: {
              foods: true
            }
          },
          infonutriday_has_meals: {
            include: {
              meals: true
            }
          }
        }
      })

Argument `connect`: Invalid value provided. Expected FoodWhereUniqueInput, provided (Object).
```

What i am forgetting ? Is there something more to do with the connect?

Answer (score 0):

I was totally misunderstanding concept of many to many relationships, all N-N are 0 to many, if they don't exist, they don't exists in table and that's all.

The issue was in the query,
The error is that I was accessing table `infonutriday_has_foods` and inside this table I was trying to create a new food and use the connect, what was incorrect since the food was previously created.

Finally I've made this and it worked perfectly:

```js
infonutriday_has_foods: foods_id ? {
  create: foods_id.map((foodId: number) => ({
    foods: {
      connect: {
        id: foodId,
      },
    },
  })),
} : undefined,
    
infonutriday_has_meals: meals_id ? {
  create: meals_id.map((mealId: number) => ({
    meals: {
      connect: {
        id: mealId,
      },
    },
  })),
} : undefined,
```